# JsException(PythonError: JsException: Error: Object has already been destroyed The object was of type "coroutine" and had repr "" )

Tags: python, html, flask, pyscript

iam not web devoloper making a simple flask app with pyscript woring or bud afterthis error comein

JsException(PythonError: JsException: Error: Object has already been destroyed The object was of type "coroutine" and had repr "" )

---

flask code

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import request, jsonify



app=Flask(__name__,template_folder='templates')


@app.route('/')
def Dta():
    if request.is_json:
        data = 'data to response'
        return jsonify({'data':data})

    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

---

### HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>

    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Cripto</p>
    <p id = 'data'>/</p>
    

    <py-script>
        from pyodide.http import pyfetch
        async def make_requst(url, method, headers=None):
            if not headers:
                headers={
                    'X-Requested-With' : 'XMLHttpRequest',
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                }
            
            responce = await pyfetch(url=url, method= method,headers = headers)
            return await responce.json()

        async def get_data():
            data = await make_requst(url='/', method='GET')
            pyscript.write('data', data['data'])
        get_data()
    </py-script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

---

[image: this is error text added fine buy why error]

-----------------------------------------------------------------

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error: Object has already been destroyed The object was of type
> "coroutine" and had repr ""

That error means that your code is using asynchronous events and you have not imported a required Python package to support that. Anytime you use the keywords **async** and **await** in PyScript, you must import a supporting package.

In your PyScript code add:

```
import asyncio
```